# Running a Bash script with correct syntax but it keeps giving me a syntax error

Tags: bash, shell, server, syntax-error, application-restart

I have been trying to compile my Bash script but I keep getting this syntax error even though I'm following the correct syntax.

Code:

```
    #!/bin/sh
set -u
SERVICE_NAME=Server
PATH_TO_JAR=/usr/local/MyProject/MyJar.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/Server-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f "$PID_PATH_NAME" ]; then
             nohup java -cp '/home/ubuntu/ResumeParser/ResumeParser/ResumeTransducerbin/* :/home/ubuntu/ResumeParser/ResumeParser/GATEFiles/lib/*:/home/ubuntu/.../ServerTest' /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -cp '/home/ubuntu/ResumeParser/ResumeParser/ResumeTransducerbin/*:/home/ubuntu/... ServerTest' /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

When I run: sudo service Server start

```
    /etc/init.d/Server: 9: /etc/init.d/Server: Syntax error: "then" unexpected     (expecting ";;")
```

When I run: bash -n Server

```
Server: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
Server: line 9: `        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a `case ... esac` above the `if` statement? Perhaps `esac` is missing or eaten by some unclosed quotes.

Comment: How are you getting one error "OR" another error? Why are you not just getting either one or both?

Comment: SERVICE_NAME=Server
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/Server-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f "$PID_PATH_NAME" ]; then
             nohup java -cp '/home/ubuntu/.../ServerTest  /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;


The error msg I see is - 

$ sudo service Server start
/etc/init.d/Server: 9: /etc/init.d/Server: Syntax error: "then" unexpected (expecting ";;")

Comment: @that other guy: 
I used "bash -n Server" to check for my bash error. That's how I got the second set of error msgs.

Comment: @WalterA Yes I do have a case esac.

Comment: @John1024 I apologize. I have edited my question and pasted the code I'm using there. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @srao That is much better.  Thank you.

Comment: @srao The error message shown for `bash -n Server` does not match the code shown in the question.  You may see the difference in code as small but small things can make a big difference in shell code.

Comment: you have to add an argument: `bash -n Server start` or another problem arises. BTW I tested your shell in MSYS got no syntax errors. Can you run ANY other script without problems?

Comment: I tried `bash -n` on the code shown and also received no error message.

Comment: @srao What editor did you use to create the script?  A common cause of strange errors like this is an editor which inserts look-alike unicode characters in place of shell-useful ASCII characters.

Comment: First thing to check: does your script have DOS line endings? See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info for some more debugging help.

Comment: Sublime text. 
It seems like there was a unicode non-breaking space from my editor. It works fine now! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure the value of `$PID_PATH_NAME` 
**or** 
try with  if `[ ! -f "$PID_PATH_NAME" ];` -> just to make sure PID_PATH_NAME not adding extra attributes/characters.

But I would suggest to run static tool on shell/bash scripts to find crazy/simple problems like this.

[Static tool to verify shell scripts syntax](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: The tool helped me identify unicode non-breaking spaces that were inserted by my editor. Thank you! It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Crash can occur `PID_PATH_NAME` is empty/undefined or even has spaces in it

Shell sees that as `if [ ! ]; then`

Prefer

```
if [ ! -f "$PID_PATH_NAME" ]; then
```

In addition, if `PID_PATH_NAME` has a chance to be empty, instead of getting a strange behavior (testing if an empty filename exists is always false), you can check like this prior to testing if the file exists:

In that case, I have adapted it to your argument parsing, because if you pass no argument to your script it fails in a not very user-friendly fashion:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
   echo "no command defined: should be start, restart, stop. Aborting"
   exit 1
fi
```

Comment: My thought exactly! File names are good to always surround with `"`.

Comment: If you test them, you will find that `[ ! ]` and `[ ! -f ]` and `[ ! -f "" ]` are all valid test commands and do not cause errors.  They may not be _useful_ test commands but they are not syntax errors that would cause an error message to print.

Comment: Ok, so it's not the root cause. You're right, we should see the full file, must be something before then.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have updated my question and pasted the whole code I'm using there. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to have

```
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions
```

before the case statement